# Scoping Bean by non-qualifier annotation

Tags: java, cdi

Suppose I have a class, `RecordSender`, whose constructor takes a target name. To CDI-ify this class, I might write a producer like this, that inspects the injection point to find an annotation called `Topic` (not a Qualifier, as the producer method cannot be annotated with all possible values of topic names that it could produce):

```
@Produces
public RecordSender getRecordSender(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return new RecordSender(injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Topic.class).value());
}
```

But suppose this `RecordSender` class is rather heavy but threadsafe, and therefore should be shared as much as possible. This means that I want any injection sites that look like `@Inject @Topic("FooBar") RecordSender fooBarSender` to share the same instance of `RecordSender` that was constructed with FooBar as the name.

We cannot mark the producer method as ApplicationScoped, as RecordSenders may only be shared amongst injection points with the same name. We cannot make @Topic a Qualifier, as the producer method will not be annotated with this qualifier. What is the CDI approach to this problem?

My vision would be an annotation that optionally accompanies a scope annotation, maybe ScopedTo, whose parameter is a non-qualifier annotation class which would force separation of scope for the beans they annotate. So for example, `@ApplicationScoped @ScopedTo(Topic.class)` on the producer method would be the answer to my question (one RecordSender per unique Topic annotation per application)

Comment: 1) Do you want to bind initialization to the already annotated points? Or you will annotate injection points *additionally* so that it helps to initialize your bean properly? In other words, will the "users" of your bean just inject it or will they have also to add a new annotation and should care how exactly they do that?

Comment: 2) How do you know that this class *is rather heavy*? Do you have any metrics? Do you have any measurements that show how it affects performance or memory usage? May be the impact is very small and there is no reason for a complex solution.

Comment: May or may not help your situation, but you can make `@Topic` a `@Qualifier` with a `@Nonbinding` attribute (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#qualifier_annotation_members)).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to write a portable extension that scans and categorizes relevant injection points, and then, in an observer method that observes `AfterBeanDiscovery` events, [programmatically adds beans](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/AfterBeanDiscovery.html#addBean--) in `ApplicationScoped` scope for each relevant injection point category.  Then there is no need for the dynamic `InjectionPoint` selection that you currently have to do in your producer method.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to go the extension route.

However, another simpler approach could be to have the producer in an application scoped bean. This bean could contain some kind of cache (a map with weak values may do the job). That way if one already exists for the given type you can return the cached version, otherwise create the new object and cache before returning from the producer. The key could be pulled from your topic annotation. If this is a qualifier, the topic attribute can be marked non binding.